# Check field value, do a calculation (division) and update column values

Tags: mysql

I need to make some calculation in MySQL table which contains hundreds of rows.

I've got a field called "`VAT-Code`" which contain a code : 1 or 2

I've got a field called "`Price`" which contain the price

Query should do the following :

If "`VAT-Code`" value = 1 calculate `"Price" / 1,08` -> update the field value

If "`VAT-Code`" value = 2 calculate "`Price" / 1,025` -> update the field value

Ok I have tried this :

I have tried this :

```
UPDATE jos_tempcsv SET selling price = CASE `VAT-Code` WHEN = 1 THEN `selling price`/1.08 WHEN = 2 THEN `selling price`/1.025 ELSE NULL END
```

selling price is the field with the price

But I get the following error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'price = CASE `VAT-Code` WHEN = 1 THEN `selling price`/1.08 WHEN = 2 THEN `sellin' at line 1

Comment: Consider constructing a separate table to hold the values associated with VAT codes at a given date. And don't use '-' in column names

Comment: Data provider is delivering column names with '-' and space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `UPDATE` with `CASE`:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourfield=CASE `VAT-Code` WHEN 1 THEN `Price`/1.08 WHEN 2 THEN `Price`/1.025 ELSE NULL END;
```

Or you can run this as two separate UPDATEs:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET yourfield=`Price`/1.08 WHERE `VAT-Code`=1;
UPDATE yourtable SET yourfield=`Price`/1.025 WHERE `VAT-Code`=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below sql query :

```
UPDATE yourtable table1,(SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE VAT-Code = 1) table2 SET table1.yourfield = (table2.price/1.08) WHERE table1.VAT-Code = 1

UPDATE yourtable table1,(SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE VAT-Code = 2) table2 SET table1.yourfield = (table2.price/1.025) WHERE table1.VAT-Code = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This query works fine now :

```
UPDATE jos_tempcsv SET `selling price` = `selling price`/1.08 WHERE `VAT-Code`=1;

UPDATE jos_tempcsv SET `selling price` = `selling price`/1.025 WHERE `VAT-Code`=2;
```

Two queries in one

```
UPDATE jos_tempcsv SET `selling price` = CASE `VAT-Code` WHEN 1 THEN `selling price`/1.08 WHEN 2 THEN `selling price`/1.025 ELSE NULL END;
```